# How to run a yes/no query on QGIS using multiple layers for specific requirements?

Tags: qgis, query

I am unsure how to really word my question properly. However, I am attempting to do something specific with the data I have obtained.
I have some different layers, such as soil, topography, temperature, precipitation, water table depth etc... and I want to run some crops through those layers to figure out where specific crops would be most suitable to grow in my state.

I am not sure how to start with running a yes/no query and displaying areas that the crop can grow in. Is this even possible?

I am pretty new, so any tools I can look into that can avoid using scripts would be very helpful!

Comment: You need to determine the conditions first, we don't have your data so can't advise on thresholds; what you're trying to do is a multivariate site suitability analysis, have a read of https://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Suitability_analysis#:~:text=Suitability%20analysis%2C%20or%20site%20selection,area%20for%20a%20particular%20use. When you can express 'good' and 'bad' in mathematical (greater than or less than) or logical terms (covered by or not covered by) the overlay is relatively simple... know your data first and the final result will be relatively easy to reach.